# Trying to return a maximum date using d3.max

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have code like the following:

```
var latestMth
d3.csv(barDataCSV_Mth, function(rows) {
    x = rows.map(function(d) {
        return {
            "month": parseDate(d.dt)
        };
    })
    latestMth = d3.max(d3.values(x));
});
```

the data in "barDataCSV_Mth" is like this:

```
measure,group,dt,amount
Revenue,B,11/1/2015,10
Revenue,B,12/1/2015,23456
Revenue,B,1/1/2016,2346
Revenue,B,2/1/2016,2346
Revenue,B,3/1/2016,656
Revenue,B,4/1/2016,346
Revenue,B,5/1/2016,2346
Revenue,B,6/1/2016,346
Revenue,B,7/1/2016,2346
```

Why is it returning 2015 as the max?

---

note

I'm using d3.v3.
The parse date function is: `var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;`

Comment: What's the `parseDate` function look like?

Comment: @Mark I've added definition to post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d3.max`:

> Returns the maximum value in the given array using natural order

What you have now is an array of *objects*, and that's why it doesn't work.

**Solution 1**

One option is changing your `x` variable, so you have a flat array of values upon which `d3.max` can work:

```
x = rows.map(function(d) {
    return  parseDate(d.dt)
});
latestMth = d3.max(d3.values(x));

console.log(latestMth);//returns Fri Jul 01 2016
```

**Solution 2**

Alternatively, if you don't want to change `x`, don't use `d3.values`, which:

> Returns an array containing the property values of the specified object.

Instead, use `map`.

As a matter of fact, this "solution 2" is the preferred solution, since `map` is the most common way to find the max/min in an array of objects using `d3.max` or `d3.min`:

```
latestMth = d3.max(x.map(d=>d.month));
```

Doing that, you can keep `x` as an array of objects:

```
x = rows.map(function(d) {
    return {
        "month": parseDate(d.dt)
    };
});
latestMth = d3.max(x.map(d=>d.month));

console.log(latestMth);//returns Fri Jul 01 2016
```

Comment: Solution 2 could be simplified by supplying an accessor function instead of doing the `map` yourself: `d3.max(x, d => d.month)`. I think this should be considered the most common way, don't you think?

Comment: for both `latestMth = d3.max(x.map(d=>d.month));` and  `d3.max(x, d => d.month)` I get a "d is undefined" error inside d3.v3 .... do I need to use v4 for this functionality?

Comment: Nope, that's just the first argument. And I tested my answer on Plunker, it's working. The only difference between version 3 and 4 is the function to parse the date.

Comment: On a second thought, it seems that your browser doesn't support fat arrow functions (extremely unlikely). But it doesn't hurt to try: please, change the fat arrows to normal functions and tell me if it works.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - my mistake - it seemed that some post formatting that I was applying to the date was causing the exception. Both your solutions are ok - I've gone with the second as you say it is better practice. Thanks again for your help and patience.

Comment: @whytheq Your parse function will return a date object, which has no [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Properties) `month`. To get to the month value you need to use [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) instead. You could either create your objects like `{"month": parseDate(d.dt).getMonth() }` or access the month value when determining the max like `d3.max(x, d => d.month.getMonth())`.

Comment: for some reason when I display the visual in a sharepoint webpart via IE it does not like the second approach - in fireF and Chrome it is happy enough ...strange. I'll just use the first approach as it works fine in all three browsers.

Comment: @whytheq As mentioned by Gerardo in his [comment](/q/40709961/trying-to-return-a-maximum-date-using-d3-max#comment68662038_40710773) above, this is due to IE [not supporting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility) fat arrow functions; this becomes available as of Edge, though. However, as he furthermore has it, this is definitely the preferred way of doing it. Using a normal function expression instead should do the trick: `d3.max(x, function(d) { return d.month; })`.